# Textbooks that define an infinite series as an ordered pair of sequences, the sequence of terms and the sequence of partial sums?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, reference-request

In section 13-2 "Infinite Series" on p. 191 of his *Fundamentals of Abstract Mathematics* (Addison-Wesley, 1966), Andrew Gleason writes:

> Most classical books define an infinite series to be a notation, not a mathematical object. Some modern books define it to be an ordered pair of sequences, the sequence of terms and the sequence of partial sums.

Gleason doesn't specify what modern (as of 1966, the year of publication of Gleason's textbook) books define an infinite series to be an ordered pair of sequences, nor does his textbook have a bibliography.

Could you please name some books, no matter the year of publication (can be later than 1966), which define infinite series this way?

Comment: I have probably went through several dozens of books, cautiously underestimating, but never have come across such a notion.

Comment: @uniquesolution After trying unsuccessfully to find a book that defines a series as Gleason described: as an ordered pair of sequences, one for the coefficients, and the other for the partial sums, I've come to think that perhaps Gleason never really encountered a book that does so explicitly. However there are books that do so implicitly, by defining a series as the sequence of partial sums and notating it as $\sum a_n$, where $a_n$ are the coefficients. Probably the books that do so are those books that Gleason had in mind.